# Is there a limit in pdf file size?

Tags: pdf, limit

I want to archive my documents in pdf. Some of documents are very big.
Is there a limit in the pdf size?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an architectural limit for PDF file.
As file offset information must be expressed in 10 digits in cross reference (xref) table, the maximum size of a PDF file is limited to 10 digits which means 10GB.

Comment: That limitation only applies to PDF files that use the older xref table format (PDF 1.4 and earlier). PDF 1.5 and later can have compressed object streams which support much larger file sizes.