# iText 7 Combining PDF's System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm trying to write a script to merge ~ 10,000  pdf's into a single file using iText 7 and c#.

My test files are ~5mb each and at around the 270 mark I start getting System.OutOfMemoryException ' s - even though I can see from task manager that I'm only using less than 25% of the available memory.

Heres the code

```
string sourceFolder = @"C:\Work\Generated5\";
string outputPath = @"C:\Work\MergeTest.pdf";
int i = 0;
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder,"*.pdf");

if (files.Length > 0)
{
    Array.Sort(files);

    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputPath)))
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {

                using (var reader = new PdfReader(file))
                {
                    using (PdfDocument sourceDoc = new PdfDocument(reader))
                    {
                        sourceDoc.CopyPagesTo(1, sourceDoc.GetNumberOfPages(), pdf);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.Message.Dump(file);
            }

            if (i % 200 == 0)
            {
                //desperate attempt to free some memory  - doesn't really help
                GC.Collect(3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've found many examples online and here on stack overflow on doing this type of thing.  However the documentation and previous answers I have found are out of date and in iTextSharp and some in iText 5.   The classes used don't seem to be supported anymore in iText 7 and the only example I've been able to find is "How NOT to merge.."

Some stuff I've tried:

- Enabling SmartMode on the pdf writer
- Enabling Compression on the pdfwriter  (got to about 1600 pdf's before throwing exceptions)
- using PdfMerger instead of PdfDocument.copyPages
- Force some Garbage Collection every X documents

Comment: Why don't you do it in batches? Combine 20, write to disk, combine 20 more, etc.?

Comment: It will need a number of passes to get 1 file and I will need to make sure the results stay in order but I will try that. I  am still quite keen to understand why my code fails.

Comment: Just debug it. There is a Diagnostic tools build into Visual Studio which can show you how much memory does your application consume.

Comment: 10 000 * 5Mb = 50 000Mb (~49Gb). Do you have 49+ Gb of free RAM?

Comment: You can even improve the efficiency of the batch merging by experimenting with different sizes and levels of batches. 10k files in batches of 20 L1 (level 1) PDF files will result in 500 L2 files. 500 files in batches of 20 L2 PDF files will result in 25 L3 files. And then finally merge those 25 L3 files into one L4 file. Indeed, you will have to make sure that the results stay in order, and maybe you will need different numbers of files per level. Sounds like an interesting exercise in memory optimization.

Comment: have you tried any of the flush methods yet?

Comment: @vasily.sib  I'm writing to disk in the sample not to a memory stream.  I've got plenty of disk space tho

Comment: @Bacon  no I haven't tried any of the flush methods?

Comment: @vasily.sib  also Its breaking after 270 files which is ~1.4 gb .

Comment: @Twisted usually flush writes to disk and clears buffers, thats why i was aksing

Comment: @Bacon  I Tried flushing the PdfWriter every 200 files  - didn't make a difference :-(

Comment: I've also been experimenting with batching - it's a bit hit and miss - sometimes it works sometimes you get the OutOfMemoryException.   I tried running the batches in parrallel so speed things up a little and I always get the exception.   Task manager still shows on 7gb of 32gb memory used.   I've got to say that the batching feels like hacking a solution around an issue instead of tackling the issue itself

Comment: @Twisted are you running `x64` build?

Comment: @orhtej2 That does seem to be a big part of the issue - thanks!  I was running it in 32bit linqpad.  I switched to 64bit and It works much better.  It still seems to run out of memory eventually but but I can see it actually run out of memory in task manager. - I will try this in combination with batching / flushing and see where that gets me.

Comment: Having made further progress My issues where a combination of not running an x64 build and hitting the maximum pdf file size as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23558676/428280.     @orhtej2 - if you want to add an answer I will give you the tick

Comment: @Twisted I feel like you should write the answer yourself given there were way more steps involved.